# How to share NAT network with computers in host-only network on Windows 11?

Tags: windows-11, vmware-workstation, windows-networking

I am trying to understand Windows networking when configured as a VM in VMWare and am facing a problem.

I have a NAT network (N1) and a host only network (N2) in my host. I want my W11 VM to get its internet connection from N1. All my Linux VMs would be in N2 and would use the W11 VM as the gateway to access internet.

I have configured my W11 VM with two network interfaces - eth0 is connected to N1 and eth1 to N2. My Linux VM has only one interface which is in N2.

With this configuration, network access works properly on my W11. Then I select the "Allow other network users to connect through ..." checkbox on eth1. As soon as I do this, my W11 VM loses internet connection. **route print** shows that all routes through eth0 have vanished including the default route.

Why is this happening ?

Comment: `checkbox on eth1` AFAICT to enable ICS you should check the checkbox on the interface that provides the Internet connection (instead of the interface that connects to the network that would like to use the shared connection). As per your description that means you should check the one on `eth0` ("WAN"), not `eth1` ("LAN").

Comment: Btw, ICS would probably run a DHCP server (which should offer default gateway and dns server "options"), while the hypervisor probably also run one (that does not offer the two "Internet"-related "options"; and even if it does it would be wrong ones to use in your desired setup), so unless you are going to use static IP configuration only on N2 hosts, disable the hypervisor's DHCP server. (Also, *don't* set default gateway on the ICS host's `eth1`.)

Comment: Is there any particular reason you have a pool of Linux VMs, but need/want to use a Windows VM as a router? (why not use an additional Linux VM as the router?)

Comment: @Attie, there is a VPN connection in the Windows VM that I want to share with my Linux VMs. The VPN client is not supported on Linux.

Comment: @TomYan, there is no 'share' option for eth0. And both eth0 and eth1 have IP addresses  assigned by vmware's DHCP service.

Comment: Well, apparently it's because you haven't uncheck the box in `eth1`. If you do that you would be able to see the `Sharing` tab again on other interfaces. Also, if what you want is to share the VPN connection, you would need to check the box on the VPN adapter instead, not the one on `eth0`. `eth1 have IP addresses assigned by vmware's DHCP service` As I said, you should disable it for N2, because once you enabled ICS properly, the ICS host would have a DHCP server up. You'll need the N2 hosts' DHCP client to get IP et al. from it instead, otherwise the IP configuration on them would be wrong.

Comment: Note that some old post / article might tell you to disable the vmware dhcp server system serivce. Don't. Just uncheck the corresponding box for N2: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-h5ZJIzXDGcM/YRJTB2kTFVI/AAAAAAAAAps/GDmoYoTXZ3kFQ7HWkrZ3oyz8xVS2OxMtACLcBGAsYHQ/w640-h565/image.png